# PHP multiple select - option data sending with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I want to change the status in the database, with a select dropdown field.
I am sending with ajax. The first row is always working, but with multiple data i cant update the second, third..etc

I tried with serialize(), but its not working.

select from database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".allbooks").change(function(){
            var allbooks = $(this).val();
            var dataString = "allbooks="+allbooks;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                url: "get-data.php",
                success: function(result){
                    $("#show").html(result);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <?php
    define("HOST","localhost");
    define("USER","root");
    define("PASSWORD","");
    define("DATABASE","hotel");
    $euConn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

  $selectRooms = "SELECT * FROM proba WHERE status='inRoom'";
   $resultRooms = mysqli_query($euConn,$selectRooms);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($resultRooms) > 0) {
    echo "<div id='reserved' align='center'>";
   While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultRooms)) {
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[0];
?>

<select name="allbooks" id="allbooks">
<option name="years">Choose</option>
<?php

for($i=1; $i<=19; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
}
?>
 </select><br />

<?php }

 }

else
echo "<h4>nothing in the db</h4></div>";
?>
<div id="show">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and getting the results:

```
if(!empty($_POST["allbooks"])) {
var_dump($_POST);
    $id = 2;
    //echo $_POST['modelS'];
    $room = $_POST['allbooks'];
    $sql2 = "UPDATE proba SET room='$room' WHERE id_reservation='$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($euConn, $sql2);
var_dump($query);
}
```

How to change, or what would be a simple solution? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you better explain how this fails? "*The first row is always working, but with multiple data i cant update the second, third..etc*" is quite vague

Comment: if i want to change the second or third... item's select-option field, nothing happens.

Comment: Is there just the one select box, or one for each row?

Comment: a picture would help to understood better the question?

Comment: one for each row, because its in the while cycle

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple elements on the rendered page with the `id` *allbooks*? If so, that's wrong, IDs must be unique. You'd want to change those to a class and use `$(".allbooks").change(function(){ ....`

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/yrkmx0rw1/

Comment: as you can see on the picture, i got response just with the first element of the database. for the rest, nothing happens

Comment: Yep, looks like you have multiple elements with the same id, in which case, jquery will only attach the handler to the first one it finds. You need to use a class

Comment: yes, it works for every element. one more question, how can i send which row to update? now its hardcoded

Comment: Also, if each row has its own, `show` element, you'll need to use a class there too like `.show` instead of `#show` and you'll need to target the correct element. How you do that will depend on your html. Id make an example but you dont show all of your html so I cant

Comment: i will accept your answer because it helped me, thank you. but i cant upvote a comment

Comment: If you can show me the full rendered html for one of the rows, I can make you an example showing how to do what you need with the update and passing the id

Comment: edited the code

Comment: As a good practice, the server side PHP script should output JSON object using `echo json_encode()`. Then in your client side Jquery ajax option set option value `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: @Janos what is the column name in your db for the auto-incremented id?

Comment: id_reservation  is the incremented ID

Comment: @barmar This question is not at all about passing more than one option to from a `multi-select` The OP has *multiple select boxes* as in, they have more than one and they were using the same id on all of them. This is not a duplicate of those questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `select` elements on the rendered page with the id `allbooks` That's wrong, IDs must be unique. You'll want to change those to a class and use `$(".allbooks").change(function(){ ....`

As far as sending the row id to the server with the update, you'll need to first add the row id to the select box so you can retrieve it later, something like `'<select name="allbooks" class="allbooks" data-row-id="' . $row['id_reservation'] . '">` would work.

I would also recommend splitting the work up into several functions to better organize your code (classes would be even better)

It's hard to test without access to the DB, but this should do it for you. Note that I have the update function on the same page and updated the ajax `url` property to `''` which will send the data to a new instance of the current page to handle the update.

```
<?php
require_once ("db_config.php");


function updateRoom($euConn, $newRoomVal, $id)
{
    $stmt = $euConn->prepare("UPDATE proba SET room=? WHERE id_reservation=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $newRoomVal, $id);
    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* close statement and connection */
    $affectedRows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0;
    $stmt->close();
    return $affectedRows;
}
function getRooms($euConn)
{
    $selectRooms = "SELECT * FROM proba WHERE status='inRoom'";
    $resultRooms = mysqli_query($euConn,$selectRooms);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($resultRooms,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return count($rows) < 1 ? '<h4>nothing in the db</h4></div>' : createSections($rows);
}

function createSections($rows)
{
    $sections = [];
    foreach( $rows as $row){
        $options = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 19; $i++)
            $options[] = "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
        $options = implode('', $options);
        $select = '<select name="allbooks" class="allbooks" data-row-id="' . $row['id_reservation'] . '"><option value="">Choose</option>' . $options . '</select><br/>';
        // .. build all your other row elements here....
        $section = 'some other compiled html'.$select;
        $sections[]=$section;
    }
    return implode('', $sections);
}

$euConn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE); 

if(isset($_POST["allbooks"]) && $_POST["allbooks"] !='') {
    $updated = updateRoom($euConn,$_POST["allbooks"],$_POST["rowId"] );
    echo json_encode(['success'=>$updated]);
    exit;
}

$pageSections = getRooms($euConn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".allbooks").change(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var allbooks = $this.val();
                var rowId = $this.data('row-id');
                var dataString = "allbooks="+allbooks+'&rowId='+rowId;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dataString,
                    url: "",
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#show").html(result);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='reserved' align='center'>
<?php echo $pageSections ?>
<div id="show">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the  variable is my mysqli connetor:   $euConn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

Comment: @Janos edited to include that line

Comment: there is a warning with the return mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0; row: Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt.. when i comment out the $stmt->close(); row, the warning disappears, but every time its false. it wont run. I will paste here an image, and you can see the table as well.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/sgsxoirsj/

Comment: i will accept your answer, because I think it has just a small problem

Comment: @Janos updated to fix the issue with closing the connection. However, Im not sure what you mean by "every time its false. it wont run.". Could you explain that more?

Comment: i get the ajax response, {"success":false}. wont update the table.

Comment: any thoughts about this? why i getting always false?

Comment: @Janos are you certain that you are passing a new value for `$newRoomVal`?  UPDATE statements are smart enough to know when a row is updated with the same data, in which case, no  update actually occurs and `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows` will return `0`. Rows will only be affected if the data actually changes. Inside of ` updateRoom` add `var_dump( $id, $newRoomVal)`, is the output as you expect it to be?

Comment: @Janos actually, I had the arguments out of order in the signature for that function. Please update to `function updateRoom($euConn, $newRoomVal, $id)` and try that

Comment: yes, this was the problem, thank you for the help!!